# Unable to map Alt + Shift+ <key> with xmodmap

Tags: fedora, xmodmap

```bash
xmodmap -e "keycode 64 = Mode_switch"
xmodmap -e "keycode 43 = h H NoSymbol Left"
xmodmap -e "keycode 44 = j J NoSymbol Down"
xmodmap -e "keycode 45 = k K NoSymbol Up"
xmodmap -e "keycode 46 = l L NoSymbol Right"
```

It works with `Mode_switch + key(xmodmap -e "keycode 43 = h H Left")` combination but `Mode_switch + shift + key` doesn't work.